# Which xgboost package should I install from Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

Please see the following figure. I need to install xgboost for python using Anaconda.

However, I don't know which of the red-marked packages are relevant for me.

[image: da]

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, when I installed the single package, i.e. py-xgboost-cpu, I was asked to (automatically) install rest of the other libraries, which I did.